# Gwt + Gae Security: Login page

Tags: security, google-app-engine, gwt, authentication

Google AppEngine's "guestbook" tutorial is very nice and clean.

It's awesome how easy I can authenticate my users via Google Accounts.

Now, imagine if my application was a GWT application.

I can make two pages: Login.jsp and MyApp.jsp then "protect" MyApp.jsp with a simple if / else condition, just like in the guestbook tutorial.

Then my web app will use things like gwt-rpc to ajax-communicate with my services. But...

how can I make this services secure? Do I have to pass them username/password every time and  check every time the authentication? Can you tell me more about it?

And what about if I want to use my own Users, instead of Google Accounts? How can I keep my user logged in? By saving the logged user's sessionId inside the User entity for example?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is logged in using the Users API, all the Javascript RPC calls they make will also carry the authentication cookies required. You can simply check if the user is authenticated using the regular Users API, as you would for an interactive request.

Comment: 1) Good. But is there a more smart way, rather than check in every call if user is logged in? I think about making a GwtRpcServletTemplate class, to avoid code duplication but I'm still confused...

Comment: 2) what about using my own users? how to interact with sessions?

Comment: @Fabio Any solution will require doing these tests. You could use a parent Servlet class that does the tests, and call the parent implementation before doing your own work. Or you could write a filter that requires login. For 2 - what about your own users? You can certainly implement things from scratch if you want, in which case it works exactly the same on App Engine as anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I'm particularly interested in the 'filter' solution, can you point me to a basic example? My #2 question was about what I have to know to write my own 'user service', I mean sessions, and so on... about whom I don't know very much! :-p

Comment: @Fabio Search for "Servlet Filters" - it's a standard component of the Java Servlet stack, and there's plenty of documentation and examples. Java isn't my forte, so I can't really help much with the details - perhaps ask another question if you have specific issues with it?